# How can we fetch list of all the kinds from a particular namespace in google datastore?

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

As per https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/metadataqueries

> Kind queries return entities of kind **kind** whose key name is the name of an entity kind. Queries of this type are implicitly restricted to the current namespace and support filtering only for ranges over the **key** pseudoproperty. The results can be sorted by ascending (but not descending) **key** value. Because **kind** entities have no properties, both keys-only and non-keys-only queries return the same information.

I'm not sure what they mean by current namespace , how can I set current namespace ? Passing namespace as argument while creating client object giving me error after querying .

code :

```python
from os import name
from google.cloud import datastore
import csv

# For help authenticating your client, visit
# https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
client = datastore.Client()

datstore_kinds_file = "datastore_kinds.csv"

# All namespaces
query = client.query(kind="__namespace__")
query.keys_only()

all_namespaces = [entity.key.id_or_name for entity in query.fetch()]

namespaces_list_with_kinds=[]

for namespace in all_namespaces:
    print(f"====Processing namespace {namespace}====")
    client = datastore.Client(namespace=namespace)
    query = client.query(kind="__kind__")
    query.keys_only()
    kinds = [entity.key.id_or_name for entity in query.fetch()]
    kinds.insert(0,namespace)
    namespaces_list_with_kinds.append(kinds)

# writing to csv file
with open(datstore_kinds_file, 'w') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv writer object
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

    # writing the fields
    csvwriter.writerows(namespaces_list_with_kinds)
```

Error :

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_all_datastore_kinds.py", line 25, in <module>
    kinds = [entity.key.id_or_name for entity in query.fetch()]
  File "get_all_datastore_kinds.py", line 25, in <listcomp>
    kinds = [entity.key.id_or_name for entity in query.fetch()]
  File "/home/vishal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/page_iterator.py", line 212, in _items_iter
    for page in self._page_iter(increment=False):
  File "/home/vishal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/page_iterator.py", line 243, in _page_iter
    page = self._next_page()
  File "/home/vishal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/query.py", line 566, in _next_page
    partition_id = entity_pb2.PartitionId(
TypeError: 1 has type int, but expected one of: bytes, unicode
```

Can someone please help , thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The bug is due to the line  `kinds = [entity.key.id_or_name for entity in query.fetch()]`
2. The issue is because of `entity.key.id_or_name` which says to return either the `id` (int) or `name` (string) of the namespace.
3. Datastore has a default namespace which is an empty string (null, None). Since the empty string is not a valid key name, this namespace is replaced with the **integer** value `1` (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/metadataqueries#datastore-datastore-namespace-run-query-python)). When you run the code in bullet 1, you will end up with a list which looks like `[1, <namespace_2>, <namespace_3>]` where `namespace_2, namespace_3` are strings. When you then use the namespace in your `Kinds` query, you get an error because the query expects a string (name) for the namespace and not integer (the first value in your list is 1).
4. Solution is given in the code below. Essentially, I replaced `entity.key.id_or_name` with `entity.key.name` forcing it to return only `string`. The default namespace will show a value of `null` (if you dump it as JSON or `None` if you print to console, for the name of the namespace.

   Note I ran your code, got same error as you and then ran my own code and I didn't get errors

```
    dsClient = datastore.Client()

    # All namespaces
    query = dsClient.query(kind="__namespace__")
    query.keys_only()

    all_namespaces = [entity.key.name for entity in query.fetch()] # entity.key.id_or_name

    namespaces_list_with_kinds=[]

    for namespace in all_namespaces:
        print(f"====Processing namespace {namespace}====")
        #client = datastore.Client(namespace=namespace)
        query = dsClient.query(namespace = namespace, kind="__kind__")
        query.keys_only()
        kinds = [entity.key.id_or_name for entity in query.fetch()]
        kinds.insert(0,namespace)
        namespaces_list_with_kinds.append(kinds)


    return json.dumps(namespaces_list_with_kinds)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to fetch the kind names themselves, you should probably use the stats entities.  Notably, `__Stat_Ns_Kind__` should have the data you are looking for.

As for your current problem, I'd guess there is some namespace key that is being interpreted as a number.  You can probably debug this by printing the value & type of namespace in your loop.